# A for loop logic error

Tags: java, for-loop, jframe

I have a homework assignment to input a string and output the number of each letter used. The logic was working when I was using JOptionPane and I have already turned the homework in. However, when I try to 'convert' the code to use JFrame JTextArea input and output, the output doesn't display the correct character count. I'm sure this is something very simple in my logic, but I don't see it

Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Launcher extends JFrame
{

    // create panel components
    private static JTextArea txaUserInput;
    private static JTextArea txaResults;
    private static JButton btnSearch;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final Answer");
        Border b = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.GRAY);
        txaUserInput = new JTextArea();
        txaUserInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220, 70));
        txaUserInput.setBorder(b);
        txaUserInput.setLineWrap(true);
        txaResults = new JTextArea("Results");
        txaResults.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 500));
        txaResults.setBorder(b);
        btnSearch = new JButton("Count Occurences of Each Letter");

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(txaUserInput);
        frame.add(btnSearch);
        frame.add(txaResults);
        createAndShowGUI();
        frame.setSize(300, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // create variables
                int[] counts = new int[26];
                int count = 0;

                String input = "";
                String output ="";

                for (short i = 0; i < (input).length(); i++)
                {
                    char temp = Character.toLowerCase((input).charAt(i));
                    if (temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z')
                        counts[temp - 'a']++;
                }

                for (short i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
                {
                    output += (char) ('a' + i) + ":\t " + counts[i] + "\n";
                }

                for (short i = 0; i < (input).length(); i++)
                {
                    if ((input).charAt(i) == 'a' || (input).charAt(i) == 'A')
                        count++;
                }

                txaResults.setText(output);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code example to only part that has problem you have found ?

Comment: Why are your `input` and `output` assigned to blank string?!

Comment: You don't have to put brackets around your `input` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your input string is empty!

Try this:

```
String input = txaUserInput.getText();
String output ="";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your input string is set to "".

You need to set it to the input text you got from the user

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need swing for such simple application.

What you are requested to do is to count char occurrence in input string.

What you should do is to remove your logic from all gui staff.

to do that create method

```
private void countAndPrintCharOccurance(String input) {

 int[] character = new int[1 << 8];


    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

    for(int idx = 0; idx < charArray.length; idx++) {
        character[Character.toLowerCase(charArray[idx])]++;
    }

    for(int i ='a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
        System.out.println(((char) i) + " " + character[i]);
    }

}
```

Then you will find out that you do not pass the input to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Part of my self-challenge was to convert to a GUI to help me get my head around that process. However, I have a question on your code snippet above. Can you explain `int[1 << 8];` I'm not sure I understand that functionality (I am very much a beginner)

Comment: That is shift operator. You shift 1 eight palace binary `1 0000 0000` witch is 256. This mean that array will have size of 256. This mean that we will cover Unicode characters from x0 up to x100 chars.